# Echo one more hour than current with end hour specified

Tags: php

How to echo hours that are one hour more than current?
I have it like this now:

```
<option>07</option>
<option>08</option>
<option>09</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
<option>13</option>
<option>14</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>16</option>
<option>17</option>
<option>18</option>
<option>19</option>
<option>20</option>
<option>21</option>
<option>22</option>
```

But what I need, if now is 16:00, is to echo it like this:

```
<option>17</option>
<option>18</option>
<option>19</option>
<option>20</option>
<option>21</option>
<option>22</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution:

```
for ($i=date('H')+1; $i<24; ++$i) {
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';

}
```

But you need to consider what to display if current hour is for example 22 or 23.

In addition you may also want `str_pad` function to display leading zeros, so the code should look like this:

```
for ($i=date('H')+1; $i<24; ++$i) {
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.str_pad($i,2,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'</option>';

}
```

Comment: dat one liner awesomeness!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$current_hour = intval(date("H"));
for($i = 7; $i <= 22; $i++)
{
    if($i > $current_hour)
        echo "<option>".($i<10 ? "0":"").$i."</option>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm at work now but this should do the trick :)

```
$now = date('H');
$max = 22;
for($i=1;$i<=$max;$i++) {
    $n = $now + $i;
    if ($n <= $max) {
        $s = $now+" + "+$i+" hours";
        echo "<option>".$s."</option>";
    }
}
```